# RLE Encoding bit sequence, not bytes

Tags: compression

I need to implement a compression algorithm for binary data, that need to work on embedded constrained devices (256kB ROM, 48 KB RAM).

I'm thinking to the RLE compression algorithm. Unless implementing it from scratch, I've found a lot of C implementations, (for example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bcl/?source=typ_redirect ), but they apply the RLE algorithm over the byte sequence (the word of the dictionary are 1 to 255, that is 8-bit encoding.

I'm finding for an implementation that, starting from a sequence of bytes, applies the RLE encoding over the bit-sequence corresponding to the input (0 and 1). Note that also another algorithm can work (I need a compression ratio <0.9, so I think any algorithm can do it), but the implementation need to work on a bit-basis, not bytes.

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure?  Unless your binary data primarily consist of longish runs of the same bit, applying a bitwise RLE is likely to *increase* the size of the data, not decrease it.  The space required for each bit count will often be more than the length of the bit run it describes.  Why is it important to to avoid a bytewise algorithm?

Comment: I know that risk, but I want to try. The reason behind this research is that I need to reduce a data string of about 80 bytes by about 10 bytes (resulting size < 70 bytes). The string contains random data, that can be completely incorrelated between them. Working on a byte basis, it is very hard to obtain the desired compression. Maybe working on a bit-basis can help (but it is only an idea)

Comment: If there is no redundancy in the data, i.e. it appears to be random, then you will not be able to reduce the size from 80 to 70 bytes.   If it were possible, that would mean that your 80 byte streams are so special that they only appear with a probability of 10^-24 out of randomly generated 80-byte streams.  So you will need to find out exactly how your streams are that special in order to achieve that level of compression.

Comment: If the data are completely random and uncorrelated, and every bit is significant, then there is *no* way to express it that will reliably require fewer bits.  Fewer bits == less information, and in the general case you have none to spare.  This is not a "risk", it is an inherent characteristic of your data as you described it.

Comment: Do you have the same probability of 0 and 1, and the same probability of 0 and 1 after a 0 or 1? If yes, then you can't compress. If no, then you might want to use binary arithmetic coding.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can encode bytes such as 0, 1, 2, 3, 255… etc. (Where lots of 0 and 1)

Let's encode this bit sequence:
000000011111110
1. Shift bits and increment the counter if  bit compare to last bit
2. If NOT— shift 111 to output buffer and write control bit 1 before bit sequence
3. If bits can not be packed — write 0 bit and rest of data
Output:
111101110100

To decompress simply shift first control bit:
If 0 — write next bit to output buffer
If 1 — read 3 bits (can be other length) and convert them to the decimal number. Shift next bit which will mean what bit to repeat and start loop to represent the original sequence

But this compression method will work only on files, which have lots of 0 and 255 bytes (00000000 and 11111111 in binary), such as BMP files with black or white background.

Hope I helped you!